# MongoDB, mongoosejs - using multiple DBs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My backend is NodeJS and uses 2 DBs (MongoDB) with mongoose. One of them has a Users collection and the other db is used for a messaging service that uses user ids.

Does .populate() work across DBs? If so, how is that done?

Would mirroring the users in both DB, where the messaging one would only have a subset of fields for the users, be an a good option?

Also, is it worth having 2 DBs worth it for scalability?

Comment: Why have you opted for different dbs? Sounds to me like the two data models are more or less interrelated on `userid`.

Comment: It's supposed to be used by a messaging service that might take more load, a lot more, smaller, requests. May have been wrong. What would be a good use case of using multiple DBs?

Comment: It largely depends on what your application does and how it needs to access data. Please provide sample code for a more elaborate answer. Also check [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/) for some ideas.

Comment: also check this previous [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361854/multiple-databases-in-mongodb-for-saas?rq=1)